# Ruby how to loop the two objects at the same time

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

While I do @songs.each
I'd like to do @artist.each at the same time.
So I can make the list.

```
<% @songs.each do |song|  %>
      <p class="list-group-item"><%= truncate(song.to_s, length: 10) %></p>
<% end %>

<% @artists.each do |artist| a%>
<p class="list-group-item"><%= truncate(aritst.to_s, length: 10) %></p>
```

Comment: Do both lists have always the same size?

Comment: @spickermann  Yes

Comment: _“So I can make the list”_ – what list? What’s your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) to combine both arrays into one array with nested values and the iterate through that list:

```
<% @songs.zip(@artists).each do |(song, artist)|  %>
  <p class="list-group-item"><%= truncate(song.to_s, length: 10) %></p>
  <p class="list-group-item"><%= truncate(aritst.to_s, length: 10) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have a list of songs for each artist:

If the artist is given in the song object.

You could create a hashmap of songlists.
So you need only one songs loop.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html

Something like:

```
songlists = {}
songs.each do |song|
   unless songlists.has_key?(song.artist)
      songlists[song.artist] = []
   end

   songlists[song.artist].push(song)
end
```